Confirm if Python script process is running
I want to check if a specific Python script is running. The script is "EXIF_GUI_EXPERIMENT.py". Running the script below returns nothing.
If I run ps -fA in the terminal I see the script is running as process "python3 /home/pi/scripts/tkinter/EXIF/EXIF_GUI_EXPERIMENT.py. What is the best way to see if this script is running?
#!/usr/bin/python3\

import subprocess

cmd = ["ps -fA | pgrep "EXIF_GUI_EXPERIMENT.py""]

result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)

print (result)


There's too many nested double quotation marks (") that give an error.
Something like this should work:
import subprocess

cmd = ['pgrep', '-f', 'EXIF_GUI_EXPERIMENT.py']

result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)

if result.stdout:
    print(f"Process is running: {result.stdout}")
else:
    print("Process is not running")
    

(option -f in pgrep matches against full argument lists.  The default is to match against process names.)
EDIT: following the suggestion in the comment, removed shell=True that's in general not needed and not only it might pose a security risk, but it can also impact performance because of the extra shell process, and limit portability as the default shell might be different on different operating systems

Don't use shell=True unless you really need to. Construct the list ['pgrep', '-f', 'EXIF_GUI_EXPERIMENT.py'] instead for the first argument to subprocess.run.
